# Best way to search on MySQL text columns

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, indexing

I have products stored in a MySQL database, it's a Wordpress website, however my data in stored in custom tables. I need to search for products and I'm currently facing some performance issues that I hope someone could help me or point me a way.

Since I receive a file (*.csv) once a day to update all my products (add, update or remove products), I have a process to read the file and populate/update tables. In this process, I add a step to filter data and replace any special character to "unpecial" characters (example: replace 'á' by 'a').

By now, I have a table (products_search) related to product's table (products) and built from it, I use this table to do searches. When the user search something, I modify the input to replace special characters, so the search would be direct on table.

**The problem:** searching in "text" columns is slow, even adding index on that column. I'm currently search like this:

```
select * from products_search
     where description like %search_word_1%
        or description like %search_word_2% ...
```

If I get a result, I will get the ID and relate to product table and get all info I might need to show to user.

**Solution looked for:** I'm looking for a way to search on products_search table with a better performance. The wordpress search engine, as I understand, work only on "posts" table. Is there any way to do a quicker search? Perhaps using a plugin or just change the way the search is doing.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we need to revise the nightly loading in order to make the index creation more efficient.

I'm assuming:

- The data in the CSV file replaces the existing data.
- You are willing to use `FULLTEXT` for searching.

Then do:

1. `CREATE TABLE new_data (...) ENGINE=InnoDB;`
2. `LOAD DATA INTO new_data ...;`
3. Cleanse the data in `new_data`.
4. `ALTER TABLE new_data ADD FULLTEXT(...)`;  The column(s) to index here either exist, or are added during step 1 or 3.
5. `RENAME TABLE real_data TO old_data, new_data TO real_data;`
6. `DROP TABLE old_data;`

Note that this has essentially zero downtime for `real_data` so you can continue to do `SELECTs`.

You have not explained how you spray the single CSV file into wp_posts and wp_postmeta.  That sounds like a nightmare buried inside my step 3.

`FULLTEXT` is immensely faster than futzing with `wp_postmeta`.  (I don't know if there is an existing way or plugin to achieve such.)

With `FULLTEXT(description), your snippet of code would use

```
WHERE MATCH(description) AGAINST ('word1 word2' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

instead of the very slow `LIKE` with a leading wildcard.

If you must use wp_postmeta, I recommend https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply. Actually, I'm not using wp_posts or wp_postmeta! CSV file replaces only a subset of existing data, so I use something similar to step 5. Then I recreate search_table but I think about your idea, to not have down time on searches. I like your idea of FULLTEXT, I need to try. Thanks

Comment: I've never tried full text search in MySQL. I think I'm going to try it out just out of curiosity.

Comment: @TheImpaler - Fulltext is fast at searching text column(s) for individual "words".  It does have some caveats.

Comment: I end up using like again, because I needed to search `description like %word1% OR description like %word2%` and was not working using `AGAINST ('+*word1* +*word2*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`. But I appreciate your comment very much